# Lasagna in a sandwich maker

Tags: equipment, pasta, lasagna

I have some lasagna sheets that I would like to use, and our oven is rather unreliable.

Is it possible to prepare lasagna using only a sandwich maker? How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Fresh or dried? Either way I don't see it as being much fun to clean up after;)

Comment: @Tetsujin You mean the sheets? Dried / uncooked.

Comment: Why don't you just boil the large noodles and toss them with sauce as you would prepare any other type of pasta?

Comment: @AdamO They're in sheets; are you suggesting I cut them into strips or pieces after cooking?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Sure, you could cut them into strips, or you can serve them with knife and fork to cut off bite size pieces. I would try a taragon cream sauce, or boil the noodles with some baking soda, and toss them with oyster sauce and sauteed brocoli like a poor mans pad see ew.

Answer (score 4):

Why not; it can be a fun project.

It will need a lot of experimentation to make it work and it will not be a lasagna.

I'd completely cook the noodles, spread them on the sandwich maker, put a little bit of sauce and cheese in the middle, put another layer of noodles on top and press it down.

Depending on the size of your sandwich maker, you could even try multiple layers.

But it will be a kind of a pizza pocket.

Comment: I would imagine that it'd be something like a cross between a toasted raviolo and a baked empanada.  More empanada-like if you made it with fresh, uncooked pasta.